# Ruby on Rails, create object of model doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following problem, on my Ruby on Rails website I have an create user page which ask for an email, password and a password confirmation. It looks pretty much like this:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign in') %>
<div class="content-signin">

</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="section-header">

            <h1>Sign up</h1>

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <%= link_to root_path do %>
                    <i class="icon-home"></i>
                    Home
                    <% end %>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="section-body">

            <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
            <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">

                <%= value %>
                </div>
            <% end %>

            <%= form_for(:user, url: users_path) do |f| %>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">

                    <%= f.label :email %>
                    <%= f.text_field :email, :autofocus => true %>

                    <%= f.label :password %>
                    <%= f.password_field :password %>

                    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
                    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-action">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="span2">
                        <%= f.submit "Create your account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <% end %>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-help">
    <small>
        <i class="icon-question-sign"></i>
        <%= link_to "Email us for help", contact_path%>
    </small>    
</div>
```

And I have my create function in the user controller that looks like this:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  end
```

But when I try to, on the website, to create a user, it does not create it. In the rails console all I see is this:

```
2.1.0 :003 > User.all
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` 
=> []
```

And here's my user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :team_id, :updating_password, :admin


has_secure_password

has_and_belongs_to_many :pins

has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

belongs_to :teams

has_and_belongs_to_many :devices
has_many :devices, :through => :credits
has_many :devices_models, :through => :devices
has_many :credits, foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy

before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
before_save :create_remember_token

validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence:   true,
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :password, presence: true , length: { minimum: 6 }
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

def should_validate_password?
  updating_password || new_record?
end

def create_remember_token
  self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end


def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end

#Find the team_name of a user
def team_name
  if self.teams.nil?
    "No Team"
  else
    self.teams.name
  end
end

end
```

Any help is welcome,

Cheers

Comment: I think it is because of mass assignment constraints in `rails 4`

Comment: what happens if you pass to create `params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)`

Comment: Do you have any validations on the `User` model that would prevent this record from saving? Also, look in your console where you're running the rails server at and see if `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` appear anywhere. `ROLLBACK` would indicate that something was wrong.

Comment: Newben: if I do that it just gives me an error

Comment: Kyle: in the rails console I just saw the following: (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'test' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK

Comment: Could you post your `app/models/user.rb`?

Comment: just edited my post, added it a the end